# Multiple fields to a single row

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Going to start with, I am extremely new to this. We are using a google sheet as different forms of sorts where we want to capture data in a single source. I am trying to avoid having to individually map each cell. below is the start of the 100 fields i'll have to capture. I am getting the error that my data of 3 doesn't match my columns of 10. Is there way to lay out different ranges and get them to all push to one row?

```
 //Input Values
    function SubmitData() {
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formS    = ss.getActiveSheet(); 
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
       
  var values = [[formS.getRange("B1:B4").getValues(),
                 formS.getRange("D2:D4").getValues(),
                 formS.getRange("F2").getValue()]];
  
  datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1,10).setValues(values)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that in your script, `values` for putting to Spreadsheet is required to be 2 dimensional array. But, `formS.getRange("B1:B4").getValues()` and `formS.getRange("D2:D4").getValues()` are 2 dimensional array and `formS.getRange("F2").getValue()` is not array. I think that this is the reason of your issue.

In order to put those values to one row of the sheet `Data`, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```
var values = [[formS.getRange("B1:B4").getValues(),
               formS.getRange("D2:D4").getValues(),
               formS.getRange("F2").getValue()]];

datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1,10).setValues(values)
```

##### To:

```
var values = [[
  ...formS.getRange("B1:B4").getValues().flat(),
  ...formS.getRange("D2:D4").getValues().flat(),
  formS.getRange("F2").getValue()
]];
datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

- By this modification, `values` is like `[ [ 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'D2', 'D3', 'D4', 'F2' ] ]`. Each value of the array is the a1Notation of the cell. And, this is put to the next row of the last row of sheet `Data`.
- In this case, the length of `values[0]` is `8`. It's not `10`. So I used `values[0].length`.

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)
- [Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)